# nested glui windows

Tags: opengl, glui

I am new to glui. I want to ask can glui windows be nested? Is it possible to make a glui subwindow, subwindow of a glui window? 
Can glui windows overlap each other?
Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes,glui windows can overlap each other, but programmer can't make them overlap each other as their sizes can't be changed by programmer.
Yes,a glui subwindow can be a subwindow of a glui window